# JQuery Validate plugin valid method always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Ok I think i'm too dump to tackle this basic problem, I have a very normal Html form :

```
<form id="SimpleForm" class="form-horizontal bordered-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Service provider</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="pname" name="pname" data-val="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Store name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="storeName" data-val="true" name="storeName" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and a piece of JQuery validate function

```
var $ValidateForm = $("#SimpleForm").validate({
        roles: {
            pname: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            },
            storeName: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pname: {
                required: "Required field"
            },
            storeName: {
                required: "Required field"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorLabelContainer: '.alert-danger',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

//Always true !!
 if ($ValidateForm.valid()) {
}
```

Its a very basic stuff and still not working please help before losing more of my hair!

**Edit :**

I forget to mention that I had a self executing function who was the main culprit  :

```
var postSp = function () {
    $("#BtnAddProvider").click(function (e) {

       if ($ValidateForm.valid()) {
          }
     });
}();
```

This function was executed before the validation plugin sets its roles, moving the validation roles to execute before that function solved my problem as so

```
var postSp = function () {

     $("#SimpleForm").validate({
        roles: {
            pname: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            },
            storeName: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pname: {
                required: "Required field"
            },
            storeName: {
                required: "Required field"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorLabelContainer: '.alert-danger',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#BtnAddProvider").click(function (e) {

       if ($ValidateForm.valid()) {
          }
     });
}();
```

Comment: I don't know the syntax of validation but I think the error element should be `<div>` not `div`

Comment: nope nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no form element which id is `#CreateForm`. It should be `#SimpleForm`

```
$("#SimpleForm").validate({
        roles: {
            pname: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            },
            storeName: {
                required: true,
                //minlength: 5,
                //maxlength: 50
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pname: {
                required: "Required field"
            },
            storeName: {
                required: "Required field"
            }
        },
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorLabelContainer: '.alert-danger',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var placement = $(element).data('error');
            if (placement) {
                $(placement).append(error);
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then you shouldn't use the variable which is returned from `validate`, just try like this;

```
 if ($("#SimpleForm").valid()) {
 }
```

Comment: yes this is correct just deleted my answer I posted .

Comment: Apply the second step which i provided.